# Looping through nth-child and change css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found a radial menu by Nikolay Talanov https://codepen.io/suez/pen/vAais, which I really liked. Now I want it to be more dynamic. I want to be able to add HTML Elements or delete some without having to change the CSS.

I'm using jquery and the calculating part is done (it's fairly simple). But I can't seem to get the selectors right...

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="btn trigger">
    <span class="line"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="rotater">
      <div class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-codepen"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rotater">
      <div class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rotater">
      <div class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rotater">
      <div class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rotater">
      <div class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rotater">
      <div class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rotater">
      <div class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countChildren = $(".icons").children().length;
    console.log(countChildren);
    var degChildren = 360 / countChildren;
    console.log(degChildren);

    for(var i = 1; i <= countChildren; i++){
        $(".rotater:nth-child(" + i + ")").css("transform", "rotate(" + degChildren * i + ");");
        $(".menu.active .rotater:nth-child(" + i + ") .btn-icon").css("transform", "translateY(-10em) rotate(" + degChildren * i * -1 + ")");
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("active"); 
  });
});
```

When clicking the trigger btn the menu gains the class active.
That works fine. What doesn't work is that the CSS takes effect.
In the hardcoded example by Nikolay Talanov (https://codepen.io/suez/pen/vAais), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this code:

```
var countChildren = $(".icons").children().length;
    console.log(countChildren);
    var degChildren = 360 / countChildren;
    console.log(degChildren);

    for(var i = 1; i <= countChildren; i++){
        $(".rotater:nth-child(" + i + ")").css("transform", "rotate(" + degChildren * i + ");");
        $(".menu.active .rotater:nth-child(" + i + ") .btn-icon").css("transform", "translateY(-10em) rotate(" + degChildren * i * -1 + ")");
    };
```

to the click method, otherwise it gets run before the active class is set.

Comment: Makes sense ... still doesn't work. Everything except the nth-child styling gets applied.